# How to assign different color to different points in a scatter plot containing different lengths of variables?

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib, colors, statistics

I am trying to draw a scatter plot with different variable lengths using python matplotlib. For the following data

```
Days = [1,2,3]
Values = ([2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6,7],[2,3])
```

I could plot all the points using the following program

```
w = [[Days[i]] * len(Values[i]) for i in range(len(Values))]

x_to_plot = [item for sublist in w for item in sublist]
y_to_plot = [item for sublist in Values for item in sublist].
```

How can i assign different color to a few points keeping all other points of same color?

Comment: You can specify the color manually, using `plt.plot(some_points, '.r')` for red dots for example. Then you just need to split your data into the 2 sets you need and plot them separately with 2 different colors.

Comment: Your program, as shown, does not plot anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `c` argument of `scatter` to colorize the points according to a colormap. E.g. to colorize all points where `y == 5 - x` in red, use

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Days = [1,2,3]
Values = ([2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6,7],[2,3])

w = [[Days[i]] * len(Values[i]) for i in range(len(Values))]

x = [item for sublist in w for item in sublist]
y = [item for sublist in Values for item in sublist]

c = [0 if i+j == 5 else 1 for i, j in zip(x,y)]
plt.scatter(x,y, c=c, cmap="bwr_r")

plt.show()
```

[image]